# A direct product of projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am studying  projective modules, but I can't understand why the direct product of projective modules need not be projective in general. Can anyone give me such example?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please try the search feature first next time.